# Will Barry Allen be gone in the next season or will he be alive and a hero?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

Is there going to be a season 2 and what happens at the alter does he die?

Comment: Wait and see..............? I don't get the point of these questions!!

Answer (score 4):

Normally, we don't answer questions about a work before it comes out, because it would be total speculation.

However, the producers of *The Flash* have spoken about Season 2 at length at various conventions. You can rest assured that Barry is coming back -- played by the same actor -- and he will (overall, at least) still be the hero of the show.

That's not to say Barry will *always* be the good guy. We know, for example, that there's going to be a second Flash this season -- Jay Garrick -- and we don't know how Barry will react. We also know that Caitlin's going to take on more of her comic person (the villain Killer Frost). and how that will affect Barry.

Answer (score 2):

Season 2 of *The Flash* premieres [October 6, 2015](http://when-will.net/tv-series/652-will-there-be-the-flash-season-2-release-date-autumn-2015.html) at 8PM ET.

The Flash has been shown to still be alive, and Grant Gustin is still portraying Barry Allen. Beyond that, we have no concrete details about how he survived the final episode of season 1.